# Objective-C int variable not keeping its value

Tags: objective-c, ios

here is an absolute brain destroyer:

**NOTE: I am using XCode 4.2 with iOS 5 and ARC (Automatic Reference Counting)**

If anybody can help explain why none of my variables are retaining their value I will be grateful beyond reason.  Currently I have this *int* variable **speed**.  Heres the basic code rundown:

In Header File:

```
@interface GameLoop : NSObject {
   CADisplayLink *refresh;

   int speed;
}
```

In .m File:

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
   screenRefresh = [CADisplayLink displayLinkWithTarget:self selector:@selector(updateGame:)];
   [screenRefresh setFrameInterval:1];
   [screenRefresh addToRunLoop:[NSRunLoop mainRunLoop] forMode:NSDefaultRunLoopMode]; 
}

- (void)createNewGame {
   speed = 4;
}

- (void)updateGame:(CADisplayLink *)gameTime {
   [factory slideViews:speed];  // <---- Speed ALWAYS equals 0
}
```

The factory class simply moves stuff around.  If I plug in 4 in place of *speed* everything works perfectly.  I have also tried making speed by:

```
@property (nonatomic, assign) int speed;
```

And synthesising and using `self.speed`.  If anyone can help, I would be very thankful! I'm sure it's something simple, but just the fact that I assign in one method and it doesn't follow through in another drives me insane.  I also have used `NSLog("%d", speed)` and it spits out the correct value in the method I assign it in, and when I re-call it before assigning.

**Update**
After a little debugging, it appears as though once the timer is created, no global variables are updated within the update loop.  If I make *speed = 4* before allocating the *CADisplayLink*, the game runs at 4.  However even if I make proper changes to speed it does not change.  Anybody know why?

Comment: Are you sure the object to which you send `-updateGame:` has received `-createNewGame` beforehand? Instance variables are zeroed out upon instance allocation, which would explain why you’re seeing 0.

Comment: Please show an example snippet that uses this class and reproduces the problem. When does `createNewGame` get called?

Comment: Are you calling the exact same object with your createNewGame and updateGame messages?  Are you calling createNewGame before updateGame for the same object?  You can print out the current object address (self) inside each message.

Comment: Create new game is actually called after the game begins to run.  The game is initialised with a speed of 1, and a boolean is set telling the "Factory" object that the game isn't being played, and the menu is displayed over top.  When 'start game' is pressed, it calls createNewGame and the speed increases and the boolean is changed.  However, in the Update method, it appears as though this change never occured, even though if you tap 'start game' again the value is listed as already being changed to 4.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, so the problem had to do with something larger than the context of which I originally thought it was on.  The problem was that I wasn't properly allocating things into memory, and because of that I was assigning to nil variables.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that speed ivar is not keeping the value? Could you try the following code?

```
- (void)createNewGame {
    NSLog(@"createNewGame: speed <- 4");
    speed = 4;
    NSLog(@"createNewGame: speed = %d", speed);
}

- (void)updateGame:(CADisplayLink *)gameTime {
    NSLog(@"updateGame before slideViews: speed = %d", speed);
    [factory slideViews:speed];  // <---- Speed ALWAYS equals 0
    NSLog(@"updateGame after slideViews: speed = %d", speed);
}
```

Do you have any code to overwrite for speed ivar?